# webpack-dashboard receives messages, but I do not see any UI

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Background:

1. I use grunt to run webpack-dev-server.
2. We exec a webpack-dev-server command, which we affixed with webpack-dashboard, like so:

```

```
shell.exec(
   'node node_modules/webpack-dashboard/bin/webpack-dashboard.js -- webpack-dev-server --hot --content-base _tmp --inline --host ::1'
)
```

```

When running the script, instead of seeing a dashboard, I see an empty screen.

[image]

To figure out what is going on, I added a bunch of console.logs in `bin/webpack-dashboard.js`

I now see --

[image]

It seems like webpack-dashboard is receiving messages, but I do not see a cli.

I am using tmux, running on top of mosh, on iterm2

The system inside tmux is on linux, and I am on a mac

When I run `echo $TERM`, I see

```
xterm-256color
```